# Initial Value Problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> We have initial value problem $y''=x^{1/3}y$ with $y(0)=y'(0)=0$. 
>   Does it have a unique solution?

I have tried using the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, but I cannot reduce it to a order 1 ODE. Thank you.

Comment: When $y$ has to be continuous and two times differentiable, there is only one solution, because there are two degrees of freedom and two initial values.

Comment: Not necessarily. Think about $y''=y^{1/3}$ and $y(0)=y'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding first order equation (let $z_1 = y'$, $z_2 = y$) is
$z' = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \sqrt[3]{x} \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} z$, $z(0) = (0,0)^T$.

For $x$ in  any bounded interval, we see that $\| \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \sqrt[3]{x} \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \|$ is bounded, hence the system is Lipschitz on this interval, hence there exists a unique solution for all $x \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

> **[Theorem](http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/204/ConstantCoeff/uniquenessExistence.htm):** Let $p(t), q(t)$, and $g(t)$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, then the differential equation
>
> $$y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y  =  g(t),\quad           y(t_0)  =  y_0,\,     y'(t_0)  =  y'_0 $$
>
> has a unique solution defined for all $t$ in $[a,b]$

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Thanks.

Comment: @FrankZermelo: You can find this result in any classical book on introduction to differential equations.